# Get Record of Specific day from last 7 days

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

Hi My database is something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id                  int,
    status              int,
    created_at          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Use case is From last 7 days I want to get data of record added on   **Monday**

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks sir , I have added postgres now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function can extract the day of the week

```
select *
from my_table
where extract(isodow from created_at) = 1;
  and created_at >= current_date - 7
```

The above will return all rows that have a `created_at` on Monday and were created in the last 7 days.

`isodow` returns the day of the week numbered according to the ISO standard where 1 is monday and 7 is sunday.

Comment: Got it sir, just a little more clarification needed  I have 4 diff type of status on which basis I want to get data aswell. For all 4 I need to query differently ? Like  in these 7 days how many records exist for status 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 . I want to get for count for  all 4

Comment: @noor: That would be a totally separate question. `a_horse_with_no_name` answered your question. You should accept it and post a new question. You can refer back to this one if you think that is necessary.